# Select2 - dropdown object id

Tags: jquery-select2

Can I get the `objectid` of a selected value of a `select2` dropdown?

`$('#buildParcelID option:selected').val();` is how I get the value but I am not sure how to get the id. This is what my object looks like

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation [here](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/retrieving-selections) the object for the selected option(s) can be retrieved using the select2 data method.

```js
$('#mySelect').select2('data');
```

This will return an array as multiple options can be selected if the `multiple` option is set to true. The objects within the array will be those passed as the data (or loaded via ajax) including any extra properties.

Example below and also at https://jsfiddle.net/6Lnpusra/ which has a couple of extra properties which are printed to the console on selection.

```js
// Define some data with additional properties
let data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    text: 'Test 1',
    extraProperty: 'Extra 1',
    objectId: 1001
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: 'Test 2',
    extraProperty: 'Extra 2',
    objectId: 1002
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    text: 'Test 3',
    extraProperty: 'Extra 3',
    objectId: 1003
  }
];

// Initialise select2
$('#mySelect').select2({
  placeholder: 'Select value...',
  data: data
});

// Setup selection event
$('#mySelect').on('select2:select', function (e) {
  // Fetch the selections array
  let selections = $('#mySelect').select2('data');
  
  // If one selection has been made print it's additional properties
  if(selections.length > 0){
    console.log(`Extra Property: '${selections[0].extraProperty}' - Object ID: ${selections[0].objectId}`);
  }
});
```

```css
#mySelect {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select id="mySelect"><option></option></select>
```